# Find a f(x) that is reducible in a field $F$ that has no root in $F$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Find a $f(x)$ that is reducible in a field $F$ that has no root in $F$

I'm trying to find a polynomial are reducible in an arbitrary field $F$ but has no root in $F$

Comment: Hint: approach it the other way. Take two irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree at least two, then consider their product.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise so I chose $x^2+9$ and $x^2+4$ as they are both irreducible in $R$. So their product is $x^4+13x^2 + 36$. So am i going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, you are: $(x^2+9)(x^2+4)$ is reducible over $F=\mathbb{R}$, but it has no roots in $F=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise can u give me a hint about another question? How do I disprove that a polynomial $f(x)$ that exist in any $F$ can be written as linear or quadratic factors over $F[x]$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $f(x)$ can exist in "any field" $F$. A polynomial's coefficients must lie in a particular field. What it sounds like you are trying to say is that any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ can be written as a product of linear and quadratic factors over $\mathbb{R}[x]$. That is a true statement.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise not exist in any field, but like an arbitrary field

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I guess I think I should find a polynomial of degree 3 or higher that is not reducible in $Q[x]$ would I use the same method as before, constructing backwards?

Comment: Take a degree three polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with no rational root. Then it's irreducible.

Comment: Yea thanks a lot!